# Filter sql records on multiple time periods in codeigniter and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle, codeigniter

Table Group_Users

```
id | user_id | join_time           | left_time
-----------------------------------------------
1  | 123     | 2017-05-29 15:26:00 | 2017-05-29 17:26:00
2  | 123     | 2017-05-29 19:00:00 | 2017-05-29 21:00:00
3  | 123     | 2017-05-29 21:30:00 | NULL
```

Table Group_Message

```
id | Message | sender_id | message_time
1  | Hii     | 456       | 2017-05-29 15:30:00        
2  | tes     | 123       | 2017-05-29 18:30:00        
3  | why     | 852       | 2017-05-29 22:30:00
```

- i have functionality like group message. where user can left or join
  group.
- whenever he left or join group his acivity stored in Group_Users
  Table.
- and when user send message it stored in Group_Message with time.
- i have other field like group_id but i removed it here for
  simplicity.
- i want when user join the group at that time show him only messages
  during his joined period.
- eg. 
        when user 123 join group at that time he only see messages 1,3.
- at time of 2 message he is not member of group.

> This is my Old query which i use before when user can't rejoin and
>   after left group he can see old messages

```
$this->db->select('gm.*');
$this->db->from('group_message gm');
$this->db->where('gm.group_id',$id);

$this->db->where('gm.id NOT IN (select message_id from     delete_group_message where user_id = '.$user_id.')',NULL,FALSE);

$this->db->where('gm.time >= (select join_time from group_users where user_id = '.$user_id.')',NULL,FALSE);

$this->db->where('gm.time <= (select left_time from group_users where user_id = '.$user_id.')',NULL,FALSE);
    $this->db->order_by('time','DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $res = $query->result_array();
```

Comment: Why not do a join between the two tables based on message_time between join_time and left_time (with an ifnull function on left_time to now())?

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thanks for your concern but i have functionality  where yser can left and join multiple time so we have multiple user periods and don't show him messages when hi is not part of group. eg here we can see user is not part of group between   2017-05-29 17:26:00 to  2017-05-29 19:00:00  and 2017-05-29 21:00:00 to 2017-05-29 21:30:00. so we don't have to show messages sent during this periods

Comment: Exactly/ That's what a join would do.

Comment: @SloanThrasher i can't understand what you want to say? can you explain?

Comment: Edit your question and show the table schemas.

Answer (score 0):

You've not notieced database you're using, so I've provided way for SQL Server. Idea is to join tables and use `WHERE` clause to check if `message_time`  is between `join_time` and `left_time`. Later check if `left_time` is `NULL`, that means user still connected, so you could use `COALESCE` to convert `NULL` to current time.

```
SELECT m.Id, m.Message
FROM users AS u
JOIN messages AS m ON u.Id = m.Id
WHERE m.message_time BETWEEN u.join_time AND COALESCE(u.left_time, GETDATE())
```

For MySQL you could use `NOW()` instead of `GETDATE()`.

Comment: Thanks for your concern but i have functionality  where yser can left and join multiple time so we have multiple user periods and don't show him messages when hi is not part of group. eg here we can see user is not part of group between   2017-05-29 17:26:00 to  2017-05-29 19:00:00  and 2017-05-29 21:00:00 to 2017-05-29 21:30:00. so we don't have to show messages sent during this periods

Comment: Provide more sample data, to test It.

Comment: can  i give you .sql file ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not up to speed with codeigniter, but here's the SQL that should return what you are looking for:

```
SELECT gm.*
FROM group_message gm
JOIN group_users gu
    ON gm.time between gu.join_time and gu.left_time
WHERE user_id = $user_id
ORDER BY gm.time DESC
```

Comment: i was try this but this will not work on more then one left or join time of particular user

Comment: Sure it will. It should return all of the messages during the time periods in each row of group_users.